# CodeIgniter post_controller_constructor Hook Running Twice?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I have this code in application\config\hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
'class' => 'maintenance',
'function' => 'maintenance',
'filename' => 'maintenance.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks',
'params' => array()
);
```

and this code in application\hooks\maintenance.php

```
class maintenance
{
   var $CI;    
   public function maintenance()
   {
    echo "Test";
   }
}
```

and this code in application\config\config_maintenance.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['maintenance'] = true;
```

and here's how my controller looks like:

```
<?php
 class Home extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model(array('home_model'));

}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home');
}
}
```

When the code is run, "Test" is echoed twice on the page if I don't add "exit;" after the echo statement. Does that means that "post_controller_constructor" is being called twice?

I am wondering why is this because as per CI documentation

> **post_controller_constructor:**
>   Called immediately after your controller is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.

Comment: How does your controller look like (or one of them)?

Comment: And you're not accidentally echoing "Test" in your home view? ;)

Comment: No, I am not, and if I change test to something else, it gets echoed twice, anything I put within the public maintenance() function is getting echoed twice.

Comment: I'm assuming something... I'm gonna test it, be back in a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, the problem lies in your Maintenance class and in your hook definition. You call the hook `maintenance` and the function `maintenance`. If you name a method the same way as the class, then this method is the class constructor. Go ahead and rename your method:

**hooks.php**

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'maintenance',
    'function' => 'differentName',
    'filename' => 'maintenance.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array()
);
```

**maintenance.php**

```
class maintenance
{
   var $CI;    
   public function differentName()
   {
      echo "Test";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. I didn't notice that it gets called twice if the function has the same name as the class :)

Comment: the problem here was, that you called the method "maintenance" which is the class constructor. The class constructor is called automatically upon class instatiation. Then CodeIgniter calls the method `maintenance` disregarding the fact, that it is the class constructor. So keep in mind, if you name a Method the same as the class, then this method is the class constructor. Better use `__construct()` as class constructor though

Comment: I suck at explaining, sorry 8)

Comment: Was wondering how to get access to my controller and tought the $CI variable here was doing magic... but simply had to add a $CI = &get_instance(); to get it!